# Unable to get async/await working in nextjs server side code(regeneratorRuntime is not defined)

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, next.js

I am trying to get async/await working in `Next.js` server side code but I always get the error `regeneratorRuntime is not defined`. I have tried multiple solutions including the following:

1. use preset-env with target version set to 8.11 in .babelrc:

   [
     "@babel/preset-env",
     { "targets": {
         "node": "8.14"
       }
     }
   ]
2. Include @babel/polyfill in next.config.js config as follows:

   ```
   webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
   var oldEntry = config.entry;
   config.entry = function () {
     return oldEntry().then(function (entries) {
       entries['main.js'].unshift('@babel/polyfill');
       return entries;
     });
   }

   return config;}
   ```

However, whatever I do, I still get the error regeneratorRuntime is not defined. Did anyone face the same issue? My Babel and next version are both 7+

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you trying to include polyfills before everything else? If so, you could just import the file first on your index file instead: `import "@babel/polyfill";` or `require("@babel/polyfill");`. https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `next/babel` preset, when you want to modify the babel config.

**.babelrc:**

```
{
  "presets": [
      "next/babel",
      // Add your babel presets here
   ],
  "plugins": [
      // Add your babel plugins here
  ]
}
```

[More info](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#customizing-babel-config)